# During deserializing byte[] to JArray is the order of content is maintained?

Tags: arrays, json, json.net, deserialization, nuget-package

### Problem

I need deserialize huge byte array to JArray.

### Question is:

Can I be sure that deserialization will be done sequentially?? 
and the result will be in the same order as source?

Comment: For an array, yes, order is preserved.

Comment: @BrianRogers thank you for your answer but have you got some link to source of this information?

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src), particularly [JArray](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JArray.cs).  You can see that it uses a `List<JToken>` internally.  A [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) preserves the order of its elements.  Besides, if an array or list did not preserve the order of its elements, it would not be very useful, would it?  If you still doubt, why not run a few tests and confirm for yourself?